# Sql Msg 1701, Level 16, State 1 while making a very wide table for testing purposes

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am making a huge table simulating a very rough scenario in SQL (a huge table with 1024 atts, of course a lot of rows if you wonder), the data type for each attribute are floats.

To do so I am using another table which has 300 attributes and I am doing something like

```
SELECT [x1]
      ,[x2]
      ,[x3]
      ,[x4]
      ,[x5]
      ,[x6]
      ,[x7]
      ,[x8]
      ,[x9]
      ,[x10]
      ,[x11]
      ,[x12]
      ,[x13]
      ,[x14]
      ,[x300]
      ,x301= x1 
      ,x302= x2 
       ...
      ,x600= x300
      ,x601= x1   
      ,x602= x2 
       ...
      ,x900= x300
      ,x901= x1   
      ,x902= x2 
      ...      
      ,x1000= x100
      ,x1001= x101   
      ,x1002= x102   
      ,x1003= x103   
      ,x1004= x104  
      ...
      ,x1024= x124
INTO test_1024
FROM my_300;
```

However an error is present:

```
Msg 1701, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 
Creating or altering table 'test_1024' failed because the minimum row size 
would be 8326, including 134 bytes of internal overhead. This exceeds the 
maximum allowable table row size of 8060 bytes.
```

How to overcome this issue? (I know SQL can handle 1024 columns...)

Comment: What are the data types?

Comment: Are the fields `char` or `varchar`? With `varchar` or `varbinary` this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: the data types are floats, sorry about that.

Comment: ... why do you need that many columns?!

Comment: @bdonlan, just for testing purposes,mmm I would like to get to the very edge....

Comment: You will have terribly sparse data.

Comment: "mmm I would like to get to the very edge...." Um...

Comment: does not matter as I am really looking for some comparisons...

Comment: I think "the edge" for float is obviously somewhere < 1024 columns. You may squeeze under the wire if you create the table first, use a lower precision for float, and make the columns not NULLable.

Comment: I have tried 800 columns... which would be the edge for floats?

Comment: You'll have to narrow it down by testing, there isn't a spreadsheet somewhere to look this stuff up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a look at the figures in the error message.

*'8326, including 134 bytes of internal overhead'* means that data only has taken `8326-134=8192` bytes.

Given that the number of columns is 1024, it's exactly `8192÷1024=8` bytes per column.

Moving on to the overhead, of those 134 bytes, your 1024 columns require `1024÷8=128` bytes for the NULL bitmap.

As for the remaining `134-128=6` bytes, I am not entirely sure but we can very well consider that size a constant overhead.

Now, let's try to estimate the maximum possible number of `float` columns per table in theory.

The maximum row size is said to be `8060` bytes.

Taking off the constant overhead, it's `8060-6=8054` bytes.

As we now know, one `float` column takes 8 bytes of data plus 1 bit in the bitmap, which is `8×8+1=65` bits.

The data + NULL bitmap size in bits is `8054×8=64432`.

The estimated maximum number of `float` columns per table is therefore `64432÷65≈991` columns.

So, commenting out 33 columns in your script should result in successful creation of the table.

To verify, uncommenting one back should produce the error again.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to change your data types to either `varchar`, `nvarchar`, `varbinary` or `text` to circumvent this error - or break the input into several tables (or better yet, find a better way to structure your data...which I know isn't always possible depending on constraints).

To read more about the 'why' - check out this article which explains it better than I could: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/23/sql-server-2005-row-overflow-data-explanation/

Comment: I have tried to make a table with 800 attributes and was Ok, do you know the limit?, I can not change the datatype of fields...Is it 8060??

Comment: @cMinor: The limit is as the error describes, 8060 bytes. It's not the AMOUNT of fields that's causing the error, it's the length of each field required that is pushing to row length over its capacity.

Comment: @cMinor: Why can't you change the datatypes when you import it into a destination table?

Comment: because, I am doing some computing, and ALL columns must be floats

Comment: @cMinor: You can always `cast` or `convert` the fields you require back to floats at querytime. In all honesty - performance is going to suck and you're just going to run into a heap of problems because you're trying to use a database in a way it wasn't designed. If there is any possible way, figure out a different plan of attack (ie try to find a way to restructure your data).

Comment: thanks for your advice, I will really do, if you like to know the max was 991 columns

Answer (score 1):

[SQL server limits row sizes to approximately 8KB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186981.aspx) - certain column types are excluded from this total, but the value of each individual column must fit within the 8KB limit, and a certain amount of data will be placed in the row itself as a pointer. If you are exceeding this limit, you should step back and reconsider your schema; you do NOT need 300 columns in a table.

Comment: And you _sure as heck_ don't need 1000+ :-) +1.

Comment: Yeah, Again, I was comparing some results and efficiency, I aggre with you that I would not need more than 300 columns.... but...